# How do violinists manage headphone wires?

Tags: practice, violin

I've been playing acoustic classical violin for years, and I recently bought my first electric violin: A Yamaha SV-200. Right now I'm making do with the pair of in-ear phones that came with it. I plan to buy a better set soon, but the wires worry me.

- Is there a set of flat-response wireless headphones that don't require a base out there?
- If I have to have a wire, how should I manage it? I move around a lot while playing: Can I somehow clip the wire to my body so it doesn't interfere?

Comment: Update: I decided to get a pair of professional reference headphones. They have wires that detach at the phone, so if they get sudden stress they should just pop out. That's better than having my head suddenly jerked around. :) They were a bit expensive, but I figure it would be a waste of the violin to get cheap headphones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest option- wear the wire under your clothes. Possibly even thread it down your left sleeve- this may or may not work for you.

Answer (score 2):

I notice that you've tagged this "practice" and not "performance". I take my Yamaha electric violin with me when I'm travelling so that I can practise without the risk of annoying anyone in the hotel. I don't use headphones at all. This will not work if you have an audience, or if you are applying effects to the sound coming out of your violin, but to hear the pitch and the quality of the notes you are playing the unamplified sound from the electric violin is ample. It is next to your ear after all.

Comment: Right, I currently have no plans to give performances with non-acoustic instruments.